# Session script not setting variable

Tags: php, session, pdo

I'm new to sessions and don't think my code is working correctly.

My aim is to use PDO and not SQL, but as I'm also new to PDO too, I'm getting a little stuck.

I'm trying to set up my $who as a session but things are getting confusing for me as I go between SQL and PDO. Can you help me make things kosher?

```
<?php
require_once('/scripts/include.php');
require_once('/scripts/includePDO.php');

$error = '';
$form = $_POST['submit'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

if( isset($form) ) {
if( isset($email) && isset($password) && $email !== '' && $password !== '' ) {

$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE email = :email and password = :password";

$q   = $conn->prepare($sql); // the default way of PDO to manage errors is quite the same as `or die()` so no need for that
        $q->bindValue(':email',$email,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $q->bindValue(':password',$password,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $q->execute();

            $r = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            if(($r)!=0)

{ //success

$info = mysql_fetch_array( $sql );
$answer = $info['id'];

$_SESSION['logged-in'] = true;
$_SESSION['who']=$answer;

//If the login details are entered and they match those in the database, forward to new page.
header('Location: /social3/home/');

exit;

// If information is wrong or missing, provide error message.
} else { echo "Sorry, something hasn't worked. Are you entering all the information correctly?"; }
} 

}

?>
```

I think everything is fine until I get to **//success** and then I lost my way.

**----- Additional session question ----**

At the top of each of my website pages, I include a php file that allows PDO to connect to my database. This is necessary as most of my pages use PDO queries.

But looking back at that coding now, it, for some reason, has some session coding at the top. Should this be there (taking into account, I assign a session on an entirely different page?

```
<?php

session_start();

$host   = "xxxx";
$db = "xxxx";
$user   = "xxxx";
$pass   = "xxxxx";

$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db",$user,$pass);

?>
```

**--- Further questioning ---**

So, finally... more session and PDO wonderings.
At the top of each page, I include a file to ensure the user is logged in, if not they get forwarded to the login page.

I'm changing this code to PDO from SQL also, and obviously have gaps in my PDO knowledge which show in the below code. Help?

```
<?php

session_start();

$who = $_SESSION['who'];

$host = "xxx";
$username = "xxxx";
$password = "xxxx";
$db = "xxx";

@mysql_connect(:host,:username,:password);

$q   = $conn->prepare($sql);
$q->bindValue(':host',$host,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$q->bindValue(':username',$username,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$q->bindValue(':password',$password,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$q->execute();

@mysql_select_db($db) or die("error");
// is the one accessing this page logged in or not?

if ( !isset($_SESSION['logged-in']) || $_SESSION['logged-in'] !== true) {

// not logged in, move to login page

header('Location: /social3/');

exit;

}


?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using PDO, so these line will not work -

```
$info = mysql_fetch_array( $sql );
$answer = $info['id'];
```

You have already fetched the row and stored it in `$r`, so you just need -

```
$answer = $r['id'];
```

---

in response to your edit.

The `session_start();` that is on the top of your included php code/page is necessary. Without it you could not do `$_SESSION['logged-in'] = true;` & `$_SESSION['who']=$answer;`. You need to start a session in order to set session values, and it must be before any data/headers are sent. Take a look at the manual - http://php.net/session_start

Comment: Actually, while you are here, I have another session related question if you're still online?

Comment: would be glad to help

Comment: I added info about the `session_start()` to my answer. It does not necessarily need to be on the top of this specific included page, but it should be at the top of any page that will be using / setting session values.

Comment: Ah, I see! I have another question, it's simple, just not for me... want to help?

Comment: go ahead and ask away

Comment: Looking back, I don't think half that code is even needed. I'm over-thinking this aren't I? I just need to check if session exists, then work from that? I shouldn't then randomly connect to the db should I?

Comment: Yes, you only need the `session_start();` and the `if ( !isset($_SESSION['logged-in']) || ...`. The rest is just redundant code. It would only be needed if you wanted to get more info about the logged in users using the `$who = $_SESSION['who'];`.

Comment: Thanks, you have been most helpful!